# How can I send SMS messages through PC programatically?

Tags: sms, remote-control

Or there a way to send SMSs through a PC programatically?
Alternatively: is there an android application that exposes an API over a socket (REST or otherwise) that allows one to send SMSs (and possibly other functionality)?

Answer (score 2):

We have a [similar question here that asks abour forwarding incoming messages to the PC over a HTTP interface.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14814/forward-sms-messages-to-http-interface)

Again, I can suggest [MAXS](http://projectmaxs.org) or [GTalkSMS](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/) which is like a remote control for your phone over XMPP.

<sup>Disclaimer: I am involved in MAXS and GTalkSMS</sup>

Comment: GtalkSMS looks interesting, however it's a lot of (programming) overhead to use XMPP for simple calls. That question is gold, though, SMS Gateway seems to be what I'm looking for. Please consider adding it as an answer here - I want to upvote this one too, but still can't since I'm a new user

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using [SMS Gateway](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.apksoft.android.smsgateway), it uses HTTP POST to send and receive SMSs.

Comment: Looks good, but Google removed their app from store :(

Comment: It may not be the same app listing as before, but this looks equivalent: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.traccar.gateway

Answer (score 0):

CHeck out this one.

Zipwhip Text Messaging: [LINK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zipwhip.devicecarbon).

This application supports user to send text from PC over a HTTP and client app.
Also, it supports PC and Mac.

Comment: How is this able to send SMSs *programatically*? It seems to require user interaction with a desktop application

Comment: Sorry not to mention, this app will be released as open source soon. About the release date, please check the their official website.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using [SMS Gateway API](http://smsgateway.me/) ([Play Store Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=networked.solutions.sms.gateway.api&hl=en_GB)) it's a hosted one and you can use their web console to easily configure the app.